# object variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, settimeout

I have the following code:

```
WaitModel = ->
  timesDelayed = 0
  maxDelay = 10

  return this

WaitModel.prototype =
  wait: ->
    console.log 'waiting'

    console.log this.timesDelayed, this.maxDelay

    if this.timesDelayed >= this.maxDelay
      console.log 'running'
      this.timesDelayed = 0

    else
      this.timesDelayed++
      setTimeout this.wait, 1000

    return

new WaitModel().wait()
```

I think this should produce output like:

```
waiting
0 10
waiting
1 10
...
```

But instead it produces output like:

```
waiting
0 10
waiting
undefined undefined
```

Where am I unsetting `this.timesDelayed` and `this.maxDelay`? Am I misunderstanding the way to make objects here?

Comment: the second time waiting is called, from `setTimeout this.wait, 1000`, the variable `this` no longer refers to that instance of WaitModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: This explains it better than I did:
http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this

Your example gives this output on my machine:

```
waiting
undefined undefined
waiting
undefined undefined
```

First, constructors shouldn't return anything, so remove the `return this` line. The reason is because `new` creates the new object and the constructor merely populates it.

Inside the constructor, `this` is bound to the object you're creating and normal variables have local scope as usual. This means you have to say `this.timeDelayed` etc. in the constructor -- else your two variables will fall out of scope when the constructor exits and won't show up as fields or anything later.

With these changes, my output matches yours:

```
waiting
0 10
waiting
undefined undefined
```

So now onto your problem.

`setTimeout` queues a *function* to run. Functions are just functions -- they don't carry extra information about which object they apply to, even if you treat them as methods (like `this.wait` does). This plays badly with `this` because in Javascript, the `this` keyword asways has dynamic scope, which means the *caller* gets to pick what it means through something like

```
someobject.foo()
```

or whatever. Inside the call to `foo`, `this` is bound to `someobject`. If we took it out:

```
var foo = someobject.foo
foo()
```

inside `foo`, `this` would be undefined. To make it work, we'd have to say:

```
foo.call(someobject)
```

This is important because `setTimeout` doesn't set the value of `this` when the timeout function runs. Instead, replace your call:

```
setTimeout this.wait, 100
```

with something like:

```
  self = this
  setTimeout (-> self.wait()),  100
```

This works because the function no longer calls `this`, it calls `self` which is an ordinary variable.

Coffeescript includes a few tricks and shortcuts here. First, you can avoid capturing `self` in a closure by using the fat arrow syntax, which automatically binds `this` in the function to the current object no matter where it's referenced:

Second, you can use @ as a shortcut for `this.` to write instance variables/methods. Thus, my final code sample looks like:

```
WaitModel = ->
  @timesDelayed = 0
  @maxDelay = 10


WaitModel.prototype =
  wait: ->
    console.log 'waiting'

    console.log @timesDelayed, @maxDelay

    if @timesDelayed >= @maxDelay
      console.log 'running'
      @timesDelayed = 0

    else
      @timesDelayed++
      setTimeout (=> @wait()),  100

    return

new WaitModel().wait()
```

Comment: If you aren't using coffee script classes, you should not be replacing the prototype object, but extending it instead. `WaitModel.prototype.wait = ->`

Comment: Alex: that actually explains another problem I had. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

jfriend00 has told you what you're doing wrong. The idiomatic way to solve this problem in CoffeeScript is to use the [`=>` (fat arrow)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) to define your `wait` method. I've also de-JavaScripted your CoffeeScript to make it more idiomatic:

```
class WaitModel
    constructor: (@timesDelayed = 0, @maxDelay = 10) ->
    wait: =>
        console.log 'waiting'
        console.log @timesDelayed, @maxDelay
        if @timesDelayed >= @maxDelay
            console.log 'running'
            @timesDelayed = 0
        else
            @timesDelayed++
            setTimeout @wait, 1000

new WaitModel().wait()
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/aYFmL/1/

Comment: You need the fat arrow to be on an anonymous function passed as the first argument to `setTimeout`. It shouldn't be needed (or wanted) on the `wait:` function, because its `this` value won't need any special binding.

Comment: @amnotiam: You can pass any sort of function to `setTimeout`, it doesn't need to be an anonymous one. It is fairly common to define CoffeeScript methods using `=>` if the method is intended to be used as a callback, doing so avoids a bunch of pointless anonymous function wrappers.

Comment: @amnotiam That's subjective. If you know the function is going to be used in callbacks then putting it where mu has is fine.  It also avoids you having to create many small anonymous functions whenever you wish to call the wait function.

Comment: @david, mu: Alright, I see that CS does the right thing and doesn't actually bind the `this` of the function on the prototype, but creates a bound function on each instance. So... +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` doesn't preserve the value of `this`.  You can save `this` into a local variable called `self` before the call to `setTimeout` or anything you want to call it and reference it that way.

I don't know coffeescript, but in javascript, it would be like this:

```
  wait: function() {
    var self = this;
    if (this.timesDelayed >= this.maxDelay) {
      console.log('running');
      this.timesDelayed = 0;
    } else {
      this.timesDelayed++;
      setTimeout(function() {self.wait()}, 1000);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like CS has auto `this` binding.

```
setTimeout => @wait(), 
1000
```

With the fat arrow, you can consider `this` in the anonymous function to be its outer value.